# How can I create a Serilog enricher with WithOpenTracingContext()?

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, serilog, opentracing

I've recently integrated Serilog into my asp project. What I'd like to do is enrich log entries with WithOpenTracingContext(). Following is the code

```
public static IHostBuilder InjectSerilog(this IHostBuilder hostBuilder)
        {
            hostBuilder.UseSerilog((hostingContext, loggerConfiguration) =>
            {
                loggerConfiguration.MinimumLevel.Debug()
                        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Error)
                        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                        .Enrich.WithOpenTracingContext()
                        .WriteTo.File(new CompactJsonFormatter(),
                        path: Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "Logs", "log.txt"),
                            rollOnFileSizeLimit: true,
                            retainedFileCountLimit: 20,
                            rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day,
                            fileSizeLimitBytes: 10000)
                        .WriteTo.Console()
                        .WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341")
                        .WriteTo.Graylog(new GraylogSinkOptions
                        {
                            HostnameOrAddress = "http://localhost",
                            Port = 12201,
                            TransportType = TransportType.Http,
                        });
            });

            return hostBuilder;
        }
```

But when I run graylog I cannot get the traceid and spanid in the structured log message, Is there any problem?

My response in graylog is
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zX7wg.png)